# Why does this resource fail to load yet Jquery loads fine

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, server, http-status-code-404

Receiving the following error when I try to add javascript file in a directory:

**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)**

The resource it's failing to load is a file called: formLogic.js

**form.html**, which is in the root directory.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<p>If you click on me, I will disappear.</p>

<script src="js/formLogic.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

both the jQuery js file and formLogic file are in the directory js but formLogic.js fails to load where as jQuery loads fine. It only loads the resource when I move the formLogic.js to the root directory and change this script tag.

```
<script src="formLogic.js"></script>
```

I don't understand why it's unable to load it from this directory yet can load the jQuery file.

**formLogic.js** contents:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p").click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's because of the relative path!? Have you tried to use an absolute path?

```
<script src="/js/formLogic.js"></script>
```

Take care of the beginning slash.
Within my Projects I try to use those to avoid relative path Errors.

If that doesn't help, please tell me your application structure and where your document root is.

Comment: I just tried using an absolute path and it's still unable to find the file formLogic.js

File structure is root:
form.html

js folder within root containing two files:

Jquery and formLogic.js